# Swift Get the Country and State of user and then change text on View Controller or Store in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, location, task, completionhandler

Hello I am trying to assign an array of Strings to display in a scrollView based off of where a user is located.

I am working on an iOS app that sometimes displays info about THC(Weed). Based on certain states in the United States I can not display certain things about THC.

To my knowledge I know this is the only way I can get the users Country and State/Administrative area.

```
 func storeStateAndCountry() {
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(locationManager.location!) { (placemark, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error")
                } else {
                    let place = placemark! as [CLPlacemark]
                    if place.count > 0 {
                        let place = placemark![0]
                        let display = self.displayTHC(country: place.country! , adminArea: place.administrativeArea!)
                        let phone = Phone(context: PersistenceServce.context)
                        phone.canDisplayTHC = display
                        PersistenceServce.saveContext()
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Below I call store storeStateAndCounty() on a login screen but, I believe the closure is not letting me finish this but, I am not sure how to get around it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.storeStateAndCountry()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()


    }
```

Below you can see I am trying to store it in Core Data and then take the data back out in viewDidLoad. But nothing is being stored. This HomeVC is where the app crashes.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
        self.homeTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Phone> = Phone.fetchRequest()
        do {
            print("Starting a fetch")
            let phone = try PersistenceServce.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            self.phone = phone
            if self.phone[0].canDisplayTHC == true{//runtime error invalid index
                self.titleArray = ["THC should display here", "THC should display here", "THC should display here", "THC should display here"]
            }else{
                self.titleArray = ["Is Microdosing Cannabis Really Effective?", "Another article with a different title","San Francisco hires Head of Cannabis","Another article with a different title"]
            }
        }catch{}

    }
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you ask for location permissions? Do you have location or is ti nil? Are you testing on simulator or real device? Did you add delegate for locationManager `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`?

Comment: Hello @tbilopavlovic Yes I have done these things. Awhile ago I had found the answer and I will post my solution soon. Thank you for you help